# how to delete data from table if the table does not have ID with transaction db on codeigntier

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have constraints when I want to delete data from multiple tables with transction database. so how to check the table whether in the table there is an ID that I want to delete so if there is an ID then transaction is FALSE if no ID is then successful and run the commit.

```
$id_data = $this->input->post('id_data');
$this->db->trans_start(); 
$this->db->trans_strict(FALSE); 

    $this->db->delete('TABLE_MAIN', array('id_data' => $id_data)); //MAIN TABLE
    $this->db->query('SELECT id_data FROM TABLE_SUB1 where id_data ="'.$id_data.'" '); //Check if id_data > 0 is false
    $this->db->query('SELECT id_data FROM TABLE_SUB2 where id_data ="'.$id_data.'" ' ');    //Check if id_data > 0 is false


$this->db->trans_complete(); 

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
    $data = array (
        'result' => 'false'
    );
    echo json_encode($data);
} 
else {
    $this->db->trans_commit();
    $data = array (
       'result' => 'true'
    );
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: I can tell just by the code color you have a missing quote, right here `'.$id_data.'" ' '); ` in your last query.  Specifically  `');` that last one.

Comment: Sorry it was an error when I created the question, but it was not the main point